# How to reproduce a global click handler with ember 1.13 (not using views)

Tags: ember.js

I'm working through the usual ember 1.13 deprecations and found that this was a quick/easy way to add a global "click" listener back in ember 1.x (pre glimmer)

```
var ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    click: function(event) {   
        this.get("controller").set("wat", true);
    }
});
```

But now that views are "out" where should this click listener live? I'm using the latest ember-cli / ember 1.13.1 at the time of writing this

**Update**

The obvious fix is to create a component - use it inside your application.hbs file and add a click handler (just like you see above) but I'm hoping for a little more guidance :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: At this time I still don't have the global click handler I wanted (to prevent "double clicks" from getting fired more than once)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the answer you were looking for, but I found no other way than to wrap the contents of my `application.hbs` in an `application-wrapper` component, to which I attached all the global click/resize and other event handlers.

```
{{#application-wrapper}}
  <div>Application HTML here</div>
  {{outlet}}
{{/application-wrapper}}
```

And then in components/application-wrapper.js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  setupWindowResizeEventListener: function() {
    $window.on('resize', () => {
      Ember.run.throttle(this, this.repositionModal, 50);
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement'),
  //etc
});
```

It seems to be the simplest work around to avoid the deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You may not require a component. You can create a global action in ApplicationRoute.

In any template:

```
<button {{ action 'foobar' }}>Foo Bar!</button>
```

routes/application.js

```
var ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  wat: false,

  actions: {
    foobar: function(event) {   
      this.set("wat", true);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I need a truly global click handler so when a navigation modal/window is open and the user clicks on another part of the page I can close that open navigation modal/window (acting similar to a jquery body listener)

Comment: The handler itself--the action--is global. The way it is triggered is irrelevant. In the scenario you describe you could trigger it with a click on a div instead of a button. Having the handler in ApplicationRoute means that you can put the trigger anywhere, and have multiple triggers, in fact.

Comment: So in your example above - if I don't want to add "action" to each part of my template how would this fire the "global" click handler? From what I can see you'd need to register the action "foobar" on everything -no?

Comment: Registering the handler in ApplicationRoute allows it to be available globally. You wouldn't need to add the same action in all your routes.